# Chrome WebRTC Screen Sharing: On stopping screen share, browser window doesn't become active/focused automatically

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrtc, screensharing

This is regarding Screen Share on Chrome browser using WebRTC.

An example implementaion of Screen Share on Chrome using WebRTC is: https://talky.io

When the user choses to share a different application(say a text editor), that app's window becomes active(focused) and comes on top of browser, and this is as expected...

**The Problem**
But after sharing this application, when user clicks on the "Stop sharing" button(present on the floating widget provided by Chrome), the previously shared application window remains on top(focussed). Ideally on stopping screen share, the browser window should be brought back on top, as in focussed.

Is there a way to achieve this using Javascript focus method? Or is this something that Chrome should take care of.

Comment: You might want to file this as a chrome bug, though I think the current behavior is desired.

Comment: @xdumaine Not sure if thats the desired behaviour because the user would have started screen sharing from a browser tab (mostly as part of a video conference). So after he ends the sharing session, he would prefer to be taken back to the browser window to continue the conference.

Comment: You tagged this as Chrome extension question, but I don't see how the tag applies. Can you explain your setup a bit more?

Comment: @Xan That's because a chrome extension is needed to acquire the desktop screen stream to be shared. The  API to get the sourceId of desktop media stream is only available to a chrome extension which has "desktopCapture" permissions.

Comment: Then maybe you can replicate the effect you need with `chrome.windows` API